# Best way to fix django admin preview of flatpage attached to multiple sites

Tags: django, django-flatpages

I have flatpage attached to multiple sites. Its admin preview chooses 
arbitrary site, which is quite obvious after debugging up to lines [35-36 of 
`django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut()`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/contenttypes/views.py#L35).

What would be the best way of fixing this problem?

I see that the `shortcut()` function takes a `request` object, so I could just extract host from there, but I prefer to not patch the live server.

I haven't looked at catching admin url yet, so maybe someone can suggest some nice solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this could be considered a bug in Django, and at least a partial fix would be to check if the current SITE_ID is one of the sites related to the object, and if so use that one instead of an arbitrary one. You could file a ticket with a patch.

To fix it without patching Django, you might look into overriding the admin edit-form template for the flatpages model so that you can put the URL you want into that link instead of the default one that goes to the shortcut view. I haven't looked into it enough to know how clean that would be.

Another option might be to monkeypatch the Flatpage model with a get_absolute_url method that actually returns a complete absolute url, including the domain, based on Site.objects.get_current().domain.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I thought that maybe I'm overlooking some quick fix.